# I cannot add Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"]) because 'index' is not defined. How can I add this Text?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a flutter app. I have built a class with a constructor in it. I made the constructor so I could customize my ListTile

Like so:

```
class AppList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
    AppListState createState() => AppListState();

    AppList({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

    final Widget child;

}

class AppListState extends State<AppList> {

  Widget child;

  List<Map<String, String>> _installedApps;

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

  getApps() {
    setState(() {
      installedApps = _installedApps;
      getApp();
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      if (installedApps == null)
        getApps();

      return ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return child; //This is where the ListTile will go. 
        },
      );
    }

}

//Just in case you were confused, I used a plugin for some of the features
```

After I built this class, I put it in my Example class.

Example class:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override 
    ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();

}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Container (
            color: Colors.black,
            child: AppList (
              child: ListTile ( 
                title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"]) //this is the text
              ),
            )
          )  
        ),
      );
    }

}
```

Then after, I added a ListTile and a text inside of it. But as I was writing the text I realized that I could not put the text I wanted. It was because 'index' was not defined in the Example class.

Is there a good way to put this text in my Example class?

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_appavailability/flutter_appavailability.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(Example());
}

Future<void> getApp() async {

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {

    installedApps = await AppAvailability.getInstalledApps();

    print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("com.android.chrome"));

    print(await AppAvailability.isAppEnabled("com.android.chrome"));

  }
  else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    installedApps = iOSApps;

    print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("calshow://"));

  }

}

List<Map<String, String>> installedApp;
List<Map<String, String>> installedApps;
List<Map<String, String>> iOSApps = [
  {
    "app_name": "Calendar",
    "package_name": "calshow://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Facebook",
    "package_name": "fb://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Whatsapp",
    "package_name": "whatsapp://"
  }
];

class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override 
    ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();

}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Container (
            color: Colors.black,
            child: AppList ()
          )  
        ),
      );
    }

}

class AppList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
    AppListState createState() => AppListState();

  AppList({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

}

class AppListState extends State<AppList> {

  Widget child;

  List<Map<String, String>> _installedApps;

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

  getApps() {
    setState(() {
      installedApps = _installedApps;
      getApp();
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      if (installedApps == null)
        getApps();

      return ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile (
            title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"])
          );
        },
     );
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put your ListTile widget inside your ListView builder?

Like this:

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
       return ListTile(
           title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"])
           );
)
```

Cause I doubt that even if you got the index, you'll still have to find a way to access your installedApps variable from your AppListState class to your ExampleState class.

And also you might want to declare your installedApps variable outside of your getApps() method just like you did in your _installedApps variable. Like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> installedApps;
```

Lastly, what does getApp() function does? And how does your _installedApps variable get data?

**UPDATE**

I modified your code and used a FutureBuilder widget.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:flutter_appavailability/flutter_appavailability.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(Example());
}


class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp (
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold (
        body: Container (
          color: Colors.white,
          child: AppList ()
        )  
      ),
    );
  }

}


class AppList extends StatefulWidget {

  AppList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AppListState createState() => AppListState();

}

class AppListState extends State<AppList> {

  //List<Map<String, String>> installedApp;
  List<Map<String, String>> installedApps;
  List<Map<String, String>> iOSApps = [
    {
      "app_name": "Calendar",
      "package_name": "calshow://"
    },
    {
      "app_name": "Facebook",
      "package_name": "fb://"
    },
    {
      "app_name": "Whatsapp",
      "package_name": "whatsapp://"
    }
  ];


  Future<List<Map<String, String>>> getApp() async {

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {

      installedApps = await AppAvailability.getInstalledApps();

      print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("com.android.chrome"));

      print(await AppAvailability.isAppEnabled("com.android.chrome"));

    }
    else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      installedApps = iOSApps;

      print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("calshow://"));

    }

    return installedApps;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getApp(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot){

        switch(snapshot.connectionState){
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Text('None');
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Awaiting result...');
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return Text('No Data');

            return ListView.builder( 
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile (
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index]["app_name"])
                );
              },
            );   
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Here is the output on my Android Phone:
   [image]

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I have added the full code of the project in my question.

Comment: I updated your code. See the updated section on my answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say this, but I want to customize my ListTile and put it outside because I am using this class in multiple pages. In each page I want the text color to be different, and in some pages I even want to have an onTap function so I could open the app when I press the text. Is there a way to put it outside??